# Problema Con Ruta de archivo Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un problema ,estoy desarrollando una aplicación que cuando vaya a la pagina principal(Index) me muestre unas estadísticas , cuando lo corro en local si me muestra las estadísticas , pero ya cuando cargo el proyecto en el servidor donde estara me da el error . 
Este es el mensaje
"**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la ruta que me pone , no agrega el nombre de la pagina que es :
 **v-desarrollo:8181/udire/Empleado/Get_Estadistica** , si le agrego el nombre si me trae la consulta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi lo tengo en el ajax

Answer (score 0):

hola que tal yo tenia la misma problematica, para resolverlo en tu layout crea una variable con la ruta.

```
  <script>
    var _urlGeneral = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

y para cuando hagas la url de la ruta

```
 url: _urlGeneral + "Generic/GetTableRequirentes",
```